# Netfilter/iptables - Accept connections from an DNS CNAME

Tags: domain-name-system, iptables, ip, cname-record

So I'm trying to accept connections on port 80 only from those IPs whose reverse DNS has a CNAME alias like, for example, `*.test.mydomain.com`:

`1.1.1.1` resolves to `boo.foo.com`

and

```
*.test.mydomain.com CNAME boo.foo.com
```

then accept the connection.

Any tips?

Comment: This is both complicated, unreliable - and at worst case: Insecure.  Have you considered just allowing access to a known set of networks instead?

Comment: _any tips?_

Yes - don't do it!

Comment: @Mark: use IP addresses or IP ranges, or better yet, use a form of authentication that can give a reasonable assurance that your visitors are who they say they are.  DNS as a method of authentication is not reliable and most firewalls don't filter above layer 3 anyways.

Answer (score 1):

`iptables` has deal with IP addresses and subnets, not with DNS records.

You have to write script, which will perform full zone transfer (something like `dig -t AXFR test.mydomain.com`), parse obtained zone file to get all CNAMEs from it, resolve them to IP addresses and add rules to iptables. Then you should place this script in cron.